# Can I load advanced 3D features of wikitude with free trial?

Tags: cordova-plugins, wikitude

So currently I'm still using the free trial. I have been played with several 2D features (scanning, tracking) of wikitude. However, when I tried to load some more advanced features like 3D tracking, 3D marker and 3D model at geolocation, I couldn't get anything in my screen. Does that means I can't use those features with free trial?

Comment: http://www.wikitude.com/about/contact/

Answer (score 0):

As per wikitude [documantation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/3dtracking.html)

> Wikitude 3D Tracking is NOT part of the free trial license you can generate on the license page. You need to request a separate trial license using [this form](https://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk-features/wikitude-sdk-3d-tracking/).